# How to pass a vector struct from one header file to class in another header file

Tags: c++

I have a vector struct and I'm trying to call the vector by reference in another header file.

Header file 1

```cpp
struct struct1
{
    struct1();

};
class  class1
{
public:
    std::vector<struct1> vector1;
}
```

Other header file

```cpp
class  class2
{
Public:
    class2();
    void function1(std::vector<struct1>& _vector);
}
```

in main cpp file

```cpp
int main()
{

    class2.function1(class1::vector1);

    return 0;
}
```

Header files are included each other and on main ccp file.
The main errors I get are for line "void function1(std::vector& _vector)"

```
Error   C2903   'allocator': symbol is neither a class template nor a function template 

Error   C3203   'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: You need an instance of `class1` to access the `vector1` class member, unless you make `class1::vector1` a `static` class member.

Comment: Make it work without `vector` first. Use a simple `int`. This will show you the underlying problems. Solve these first.

Comment: `vector1` is an instance  member of class `class1`. Until you have an instance of `class1`, There is no *there* there. You could, of course, make `vector1` static to the class `class1` (followed by fixing the linker error you'll no doubt get immediately afterward because you forgot to actually define the static instance somewhere) and that could/would "work". But it is also highly likely not the architecture you're shooting for. You have a similar issue with `class2::function1`, btw, this time with a member function rather than a member variable. Perhaps review your C++ text.

Comment: Worth mentioning, the problems with this code have absolutely nothing to do with multiple header files as the title and text imply. This code would fail even if it were all in the same cpp file with no headers besides stock system headers.

Comment: So much wrong here, I would study the basics of C++ a bit more. You need to learn the difference between the type and the instance (AKA object) of a class.

Comment: @hyde You probably refer to the missing semicola after the `class` / `struct` declarations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mostly refer to the question title, as well as line `class2.function1(class1::vector1);`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get this to work properly?

From what I can deduce of the code you show, you'll need to do the following in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    class2 c2; // Avoid naming variables the same as their typenames
    class1 c1;
    c2.function1(c1.vector1);

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### To elaborate more:

- header files contain declarations of `class` / `struct` interfaces<sup>1</sup>.
- unless these publicly accessible `class` / `struct` members are declared to be `static` you'll need an instance to access them.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Note that `class` and `struct` definitions need to be closed with a semicolon (`;`) after the final closing brace (`}`)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you the simplest way how it can be done ([online editor](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk_AE0a3N)) :

head1.cpp

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct struct1
{
    struct1();
};
class  class1
{
public:
    std::vector<struct1> vector1;
};
```

head2.cpp

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "head1.cpp"

class  class2
{
public:
    class2() {};
    void function1(std::vector<struct1>& _vector) {};
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "head2.cpp" // Only head2 is needed as head1 is already imported in head2

using namespace std;

int main() {
    class2 c2;
    class1 c1;
    c2.function1(c1.vector1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiled and works correctly:

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    class1 first;
    class2 second;

    second.function1(first.vector1);

    return 0;
}
```

**class1.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "struct1.h"
#include <vector>

class class1
{
public:
    std::vector<struct1> vector1;
};
```

**class2.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "struct1.h"
#include <vector>

class class2
{
public:
    class2()
    {

    }

    void function1(std::vector<struct1>& _vector)
    {

    }
};
```

**struct1.h**:

```
#pragma once

struct struct1
{
    struct1()
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a header file with **struct1** and include it in your "**Header file 1**" and in "**Other header file**".

I'm not sure, but may be it will work: Just declare your **struct1** in "**Other header file**" before **class2** declaration like this: `struct struct1;`

Comment: `struct1` is pretty unrelated to the problem that appears in `main()`.